# Convertir una consulta SQL de tipo Count() en una Variable "X"

Tags: mysql

estoy trabajando con un Dashboard y en el cual estoy usando un DATASOURCE de tipo Mysql-BD . donde quiero mostrar en porcentaje los resultados de una consulta especifica.

Digamos que estoy iniciando en esto y deseo hacer lo siguiente:

La consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database WHERE columna = 'dato';
```

esto me arroja un resultado de tipo `int` (entero) por ejemplo 20...

ahora bien ¿esto serian la cantidad de registros donde se cumple mi consulta cierto?

si tengo "n" registros y me trae "m" datos , quiero representarlos como un porcentaje P del total...

entonces mi consulta quiero almacenarla en una variable .

graficamente :

```
m = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database WHERE columna = 'dato';  (esta trae un numero especifico)
n = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database; (esta trae todos los registros)
```

entonces `m/n*100 = un numero entero (que para mi representa un %)...`

si `m = 200` y `n = 1000 ..` entonces `200/1000*100 = 20`

este dato lo representare en el dashboard y representa el 20% del total ...

Dicho esto, y disculpen tanto texto (es para ser lo mas especifico posible) como lo haría?

o como podría representar los datos de manera que a través de la misma bd (dinámica) pueda jalarlos al *dashboard*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN columna = 'dato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS suma, 
COUNT(1) AS total
FROM Tabla
```

O en una sola formula

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN columna = 'dato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(1) AS promedio
FROM Tabla
```

Si quieres hacerlo con variables puedes hacerlo así en MySQL:

```
SELECT 
@suma := SUM(CASE WHEN columna = 'dato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS suma, 
@total := COUNT(1) AS total
FROM Tabla
```

Luego escribes:

```
SELECT @suma/@total
```

Para tu respuesta final

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono 
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN columna = 'dato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(1) AS promedio
FROM Tabla.

No logro declarar las variables en la consulta pero de igual forma lo entiendo sin declararlas..

La cuestión era poder hacerlo mas sencillo pero a fin de cuentas como esta consulta se transformara en un Gráfico de barra para un cliente final que no "maneja SQL". lo importante era que yo lo entendiera. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Marcala como respuesta entonces, es una forma de agradecer a quie te ayudo.